# I am trying to reference a specific JSON response from an invoked lambda function within my connect call flow and transfer based on the response

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am trying to reference a specific JSON response from an invoked lambda function within my connect call flow and transfer based on the response. In this specific instance, I am getting a response from my lambda function of the following format

{"Criteria1":"Eligibility":"Criteria2":"Eligibility"}

I am wondering how to reference the individual responses in Amazon Connect.

I have tried the following: Doing a Set Contact Attributes Block after invocation of the function and declaring a variable IsEligibleValue with the value being:

$ContactData.Attributes.ChatGPTResponse.eligibilityDecision.Criteria1
$ContactData.Attributes.ChatGPTResponse.eligibilityDecision.Criteria2

and then built branches to transfer to based on those decisions with a Check Contact Attributes Block which immediately follows the Set Contact Attributes Block.

I have tried variations of the checks being "Eligibility" and without the quotation marks. I've also tried using contains instead of equals. I am still going down the NoMatch route.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your lambda is passing back

```
{"Criteria1":"Eligibility":"Criteria2":"Eligibility"}
```

Then Connect isn't going to be able to parse that. Did you mean...

```
{
  "Criteria1":"Eligibility",
  "Criteria2":"Eligibility"
}
```

Assuming so, then you can use a Set Contact Attributes block and either set the attributes value dynamically by selecting `External` as the Namespace and entering `Criteria1` as the key or setting it manually as `$.External.Criteria1`

See the documentation pages below for more info...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-attrib-list.html#attribs-lambda-table

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html#process-function-response

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/attribs-with-lambda.html

Comment: Yes, I meant:

{
    "Criteria1": "Eligibility",
    "Criteria2": "Eligibility"
}

Comment: The API Response Text is in the following format:

{
    "Criteria1": "Eligibility",
    "Criteria2": "Eligibility"
}

I tried both of your suggestions and neither of them worked. I am still going down the NoMatch road.

Comment: Sorry Micah I failed to get back to you. Can you post a screenshot of your set attributes block.

Comment: That;s okay, Ledge. I ended up figuring it out. Had to return the json response as a resultMap.